# Decode BLE GattServices data

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am implementing BLE in Android Studio. I have connected with the peripheral device ok. In my onServicesDiscovered method I want to analyze the services (and characteristics) and I get something like the following when I print out:

android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattService@41b6dd18

There is 4 services in the list and they all look similar except for the numbers at the end. How can I convert this to useful information. I have seen no reference to this format.

Thanks.

Comment: This looks like an access address, not like characteristic data.

Answer (score 1):

Try to read the uuid from the BluetoothGattService object.

You can find uuid of standard services on [Bluetooth SIG website](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/services). If the uuid is not there (i.e. custom services), you should read the manual of the peripheral or reach out the peripheral maker.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on what you consider "useful" information.

BLE works mostly like dictionary where you look up long numbers (characteristics) and get binary data, so without prior information about the device you're working on, there is not much you can see when you discover services.

That said, in [the BLE docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html), there is a method `displayGattServices()` which puts the discovered services info in an ExpandableListView, and here I changed it to print the UUIDs of services and characteristics to logcat  instead.

Besides the UUIDs, you can use [getProperties()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattCharacteristic.html#getProperties()) to find out other characteristic properties such as the format of the characteristic data, or [getPermissions()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattCharacteristic.html#getPermissions()) to see whether you can read or write the characteristic.

```
// Demonstrates how to iterate through the supported GATT
// Services/Characteristics.
private void displayGattServices(List<BluetoothGattService> gattServices) {
    final String TAG = "BleServiceInfo";

    if (gattServices == null) return;
    String uuid;
    String unknownServiceString = "Unknown service"
    String unknownCharaString = "Unknown characteristic"

    // Loops through available GATT Services.
    for (BluetoothGattService gattService : gattServices) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Service: " + gattService.getUuid().toString());

        // Loops through available Characteristics.
        for (BluetoothGattCharacteristic gattCharacteristic : gattCharacteristics) {
            Log.d(TAG, "\tCharacteristic: " + gattCharacteristic.getUuid().toString());
        }
     }
}
```

Call this method from `onServicesDisccovered()` like this:

```
public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
    ....

    displayGattServices(gatt.getServices()); 
}
```